# python dict add and modify operation

Tags: python, dictionary

I am looking for a "update and insert" operation for dict, there is a common job: for given keys in a list, for each key update the value in dict. but if the key don't exist in dict, insert a default value into the dict then update like:

```
for k in list:
    dict[k] += 2
```

If k is not in dict's keys, do `dict[k] = 0` and `dict[k] += 2` like c++'s std::map

Is there a simple way? I don't want write a if-else

Comment: Well, you're question is stated in an `if-else` manner, so **no, you cannot not use `if-else`.**

Comment: How so? My solution does it without an `if-else`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few ways:

**dict.get**

```
for k in li:
    d[k] = d.get(k,0) + 2
```

**setdefault**

```
for k in li:
    d[k] = d.setdefault(k,0) + 2
```

You'll notice that this is basically equivalent to the `get` syntax.  The difference between the two is that the call to `setdefault` actually *creates* the default value if it doesn't yet exist, so you could alternatively write:

```
for k in li:
    d.setdefault(k,0)
    d[k] += 2
```

**use a defaultdict**

```
from collections import defaultdict
d = defaultdict(int)

for k in list:
    d[k] += 2
```

(don't name your lists `list`, don't name your dicts `dict`; those names shadow the built-in types)

Answer (score 1):

When you do

```
dict[k] += 2
```

It means that

```
dict[k] = dict[k] + 2
```

So, Python tries to get the value for the key `k` and it doesn't find one. So, it fails. But we can use [`dict.get`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get) which will return a default value when a key is not found. It can be used like this

```
for k in my_list:
    d[k] = d.get(k, 0) + 2
```

Here, we ask the dictionary object to return 0 if the key is not found. And then we assign the value of the right hand expression to `d[k]`, which will either update/create a new key.

Answer (score 1):

```
from collections import defaultdict
d = defaultdict(int)
d['whatever'] += 2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
dict[k]=dict.get(k,0)+=2
```

Is how you would do it.